# Program in Windows startup registry doesn't run

Tags: windows, windows-registry

On my computer at school, I was seeing I could get a program to run when the computer started, so I registered it to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.

However, when the computer loads, program does not run on startup.  Why would it not run ?

Comment: Please share output from `reg query hkcu\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` - at least the dysfunctional entry…

Answer (score 1):

Wrong registry key; should read as

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\**Software**\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Read [**Run and RunOnce Registry Keys**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article:

> `Run` and `RunOnce` registry keys cause programs to run each time that a
>   user logs on. The data value for a key is a command line. Register
>   programs to run by adding entries of the form
>   `description-string=commandline`. You can write multiple entries under a
>   key. If more than one program is registered under any particular key,
>   the order in which those programs run is indeterminate.
>
> The Windows registry includes the following four keys:
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
> ```

Comment: whoops i forgot to include the software part.  the thing is it works on my personal computer but not on the school one.

Comment: @Jleong If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Comment: In Windows 10, there is only `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE` and no alternatively cased location exists.

Comment: @ScottSolmer don't worry - Windows are mostly case insensitive (at least registry keys are…)

Comment: I ended up here because my app was crashing silently due to the Current Directory becoming `C:\Windows\System32` and attempting to write a log file there (security ex). Originally I suspected my key was wrong, but alas...